# Google Maps JavaScript API Usage Limits

Tags: geolocation

I recently came accross an error in my production

```
This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details.
```

Upon looking into the console i found the below limit

```
To request more than 25,000 map loads per day, you must use an API key and enable billing
```

I got this error in production.When I logged in the my sandbox which no one uses,error is present over there as well.Seems like somehow this limit is share across the Orgs.I have a map on Account page. I feel there are two work around :
**First** is to put a button above the map so that the map doesn't load whenever the user refreshes the page and
**Second** is to caching my results anywhere in the db.

Can some one please share their views on this and let me know how the limit is calculated - org wise or combined

Comment: This does not look related to Salesforce at all....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visualforce Google Maps has stopped working](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161328/visualforce-google-maps-has-stopped-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind these are google API limits, they have nothing to do with your org(s).

Limits are based off of your google developer api key for that service. So if you use the same developer key in multiple places, your orgs for example, then they all count against your limit.

Another thing to thing about is how you set this particular service up. There is a spot in the google developer api key console that you can allow this key to only be used from certain sites. So set your referrers up properly so your key can only be used from sites you intend it to be used from. Since it is a Javascript API your key can easily be seen and potentially used. But if you set up your referrers properly then it is only valid from sites you allow to use it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on developer api key?

Comment: When you set up the service you have to get a key from developers.google.com to use in the script tag.